# No dual boot after UEFI lock of the hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have an account here, but the password is on my ubuntu which I can't access ^^.
I have an old windows 10 computer and I had a dual boot with ubuntu 22.04.
Ok so I tried several things on my ubuntu for a VM to work,because I wanted kali to run on a VM. The VM would charge and I had to boot many times to access the MOK manager, which kept telling me the password I inserted didn't work. After many failures while rerererererebooting I decided to look at the UEFI settings menu appearing each time I boot. I went in, and had the bad Idea to lock the hd with a password. I know the password, no problem with that, but now the dual boot no longer appears. How can I dual boot again?

Comment: I don't know if I'm understand you correctly, but I'll try to help you, whats the current state if you start your computer did it boot only windows? did it boot into grub? or did you get an error message with no operating system found?

Comment: MOK is machine owner key. Only required if UEFI Secure Boot is on. Windows or an UEFI firmware update may reset to defaults and turn on Secure Boot. Try with Secure boot off in UEFI settings.

Comment: @lucki1000 Yes it boots only on windows. Apparently there is also an option to dual boot from widows, but the only system it sees is windows.

Comment: @oldfred yes UEFI was on, but I never had to type any passwordto boot. Now ta password is asked and it doesn't boot on grub

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I managed to get back grub I used bcdedit in windows. I might have disabled UEFI

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`